# English translation of etz chayim (arizal)

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, english, arizal

Does anyone know of a good English translation of Etz Chayim by the Arizal?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect this exists?

Comment: I found one book from Amazon.com on the palace of Adam kadmon, link below. There is also the translation of shaar hagilgulim no chabads website. But the full etz chaim i havent seen anywhere.http://www.amazon.com/Tree-Life-Chayyim-Introduction-Kabbalah/dp/0979597102/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1424629189&sr=8-4&keywords=Etz+chaim

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase an English version of the sefer [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979597102). It also includes some explanation of difficult passages and a clear introduction introducing the basics of kabbalah.

I am not certain if it contains *everything* that is in the original Sefer Etz Chayim by Chayim Vital, but it is a good start nonetheless. I have read the book, but I have never read the original ספר עץ חיים so I cannot vouch for its accuracy in that regard.

Comment: Did you understand anything? Ever since, have you learn the sefer Etz Chaim?

Comment: @FalseMessiah I have since learned some of Sefer Eitz Chayim but I don't profess to be an expert :)

Answer (score 1):

An English translations page for the Arizal's works has been started at Wikisource.  As of Mar. 2021 there is just a little, but if everyone learning contributed a bit at a time (or if someone contributed a lot at once) ...

- https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Author:Isaac_Luria#Perek_3

Sefaria has Chapter names in English, and some sections have summaries or notes as of Mar. 2021:

- https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Etz_Chaim.1.1?lang=bi
- https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim?lang=bi